# One of the TableColumn doesn't show the values but others work fine. JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have a TableView with three TableColumns. There is an ObservableList named "sensorDataList " in MainApp.java that stores the objects to be shown in the TableView. With the following code, only the first TableColumn named "idColumn" doesn't show the values from the observable list, however, the other two TableColumns works fine.

[image: Image shows empty TableColumn ID]

MainApp.java (this has an "ObservableList" of Sensor objects (see Sensor.java). Also this class has the method named "showSensorDialog()" which loads the .fxml file that has the TableView in question. FYI, this method is invoked by a button in other controller.)

```
public class MainApp extends Application {
    private Stage primaryStage;
    private Stage sensorDialogStage;
    private ObservableList<sensor> sensorDataList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public MainApp(){
            sensorDataList.add(new sensor("testText","1 1 0.7", "0 0 1"));
    }

    public ObservableList<Sensor> getSensorDataList(){return sensorDataList;}

    public void showSensorDialog() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(MainApp.class.getResource("/view/SensorDialog.fxml"));
            Object object = loader.load();
            sensorDialogStage = new Stage();               
            Scene scene = new Scene((Parent) object);
            sensorDialogStage.setScene(scene);

            SensorDialogController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setSensorDialogStage(sensorDialogStage);

            controller.setMainApp(this); // this line connects the ObservableList to the TableView. 
            sensorDialogStage.showAndWait();
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }    
}
```

SensorDialogController.java

```
public class SensorDialogController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private TableView<Sensor> sensorTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Sensor, String> idColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Sensor, String> locationColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Sensor, String> directionColumn;

    private MainApp mainApp;

    public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
        this.mainApp = mainApp;
        sensorTable.setItems(mainApp.getSensorDataList()); // ObservableList and TableView gets connected. 
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){
        idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Sensor, String>("id"));
        locationColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Sensor, String>("location"));
        directionColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Sensor, String>("direction"));
    }
}
```

Sensor.java

```
public class Sensor{
    private SimpleStringProperty id;
    private SimpleStringProperty location;
    private SimpleStringProperty direction;

    public Sensor(String i, String loc, String dir){
    this.id = new SimpleStringProperty(i);
    this.location = new SimpleStringProperty(loc);
    this.direction = new SimpleStringProperty(dir);
    }
}
```

Comment: `(new PropertyValueFactory<Sensor>, String>("id"));` is `<Sensor>` a typo or is this wanted? Because in the other two `CellFactories` you write `(new PropertyValueFactory<Sensor, String>("location"));` with `<Sensor, String>`.

Comment: Oops, that is a typo. Sorry. I will edit it.

Comment: The question is still open. The above said typo was only here (not in the actual file).

Comment: Check that you have the idProperty() method correctly defined in Sensor.java.

Comment: @James_D : Thanks! It worked. Actually previously none of the SimpleStringProperty (I mean id, location, direction) had xProperty() method defined. Even then it was only "id" that wasn't getting shown (as shown in the above figure). Can  you please inform me, why this convention of defining xProperty() is important, when anywhere in the code it (xProperty()) doesn't seems to be called.

Comment: If there's no xProperty() method the TableView will look for getX() instead. So it should work with getId() too.

Comment: The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) state all this pretty clearly.